# How to represent 1) in LaTeX?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I tried just

```
1) foo;
2) bar;
```

in LaTeX, but I found it looks strange.

Comment: `but I found it looks strage` is not useful information in helping you solve any issue. In your future questions, please try and describe _why_ it looks strange, and how you expected it to look.

Comment: Please elaborate on that `strangeness`!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `enumitem` package to make all kinds of lists.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,label=\arabic*)]
    \item foo
    \item bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The key part for your question is the `label=\arabic*)`.  The `\arabic` part tells LaTeX you want numbers, the `)` says you want brakets.  The `*` is also necessary.

The `noitemsep` isn't necessary, I just like using it whenever I make lists, as I dislike spaces placed between items (which is the default).

Check out [the documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en) for this package if you want to learn more about it

Comment: Does it support inline mode?

Answer (score 9):

Are you talking about an enumeration?

With the `enumitem` package and its `shortlabels` option, we have this:

[image: enumitem]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}[1)]
   \item foo;
   \item bar;
   \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The `enumerate` package manages `shortlabels` natively:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}[1)]
   \item foo;
   \item bar;
   \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```